# Unit test for allowable checkers moves

Tags: game, unit-testing, f#

1. Is pattern matching within a unit test a code smell?
2. Do I really need to throw an exception just for my test to fail if the function under test receives invalid arguments (i.e. not Succeeded case value)?

Here's my test:

```
[<Test>]
let ``get available positions for black soldier`` () =

    // Setup
    let piece = Black ( BlackSoldier , (1,5) )

    // Test
    let available = startGame () |> getPositions
                                 |> optionsFor piece
    // Verify
    match available with
    | OptionsResponse.Succeeded coordinates ->
        let northWestAvailable = coordinates |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = (0,4))
        let northEastAvailable = coordinates |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = (2,4))

        (northWestAvailable && northEastAvailable) |> should equal true

    | _ -> failwith "Failed to get options"
```

Here's the function under test:

```
let optionsFor piece positions =

    let duplicatesFound = positions |> Seq.countBy id
                                    |> Seq.map snd
                                    |> Seq.exists (fun count -> count > 1)
    if duplicatesFound
    then OptionsResponse.DuplicatesNotAllowed positions
    else match piece |> isKing with
         | false -> let options = positions |> availablePositions 
                                            |> List.filter (optionsForSoldier piece)
                    OptionsResponse.Succeeded options

         | true  -> let options = positions |> availablePositions 
                                            |> List.filter (optionsForKing piece)
                    OptionsResponse.Succeeded options
```

Appendix:

```
type Coordinate = int * int

type Space =
    | Occupied  of Piece
    | Available of Coordinate

type OptionsResponse =
    | DuplicatesNotAllowed of Space list
    | Succeeded            of Coordinate list
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is pattern matching within a unit test a code smell?

I don't think so. When a tested method returns a discriminated union, then using pattern matching in the unit test is natural.

> Do I really need to throw an exception just for my test to fail if the function under test receives invalid arguments (i.e. not Succeeded case value)?

Yes, I think you should. The reason for that is that if the function incorrectly returns something other than `Succeeded`, your test needs to fail. And throwing an exception is how you do that.

---

Also, if you're a fan of terseness, you can write the `List.exists` predicate as e.g. `((=) (0,4))`, instead of using `fun`:

```
let northWestAvailable = coordinates |> List.exists ((=) (0,4))
```

Or, even better, use `should contain`:

```
coordinates |> should contain (0,4)
```

This is shorter, clearer and will also lead to clearer test failures.